# error polyglossia for sanskrit and hindi with lualatex but not with xelatex

Tags: luatex, polyglossia

I have `texlive` on windows with installed, all packages relating to `sanskrit` and `hindi`. there is no error with `xelatex`.

when I compile, with `lualatex`, the simple document, I obtain an error in `gloss-sanskrit.ldf`

```
Undefined control sequence. \newXeTeXintercharclass
Undefined control sequence. \newXeTeXintercharclass\sanskrit@punctthin
```

the whole log

```
Undefined control sequence. \newXeTeXintercharclass
Undefined control sequence. \newXeTeXintercharclass\sanskrit@punctthin
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Missing \begin{document}. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Missing $ inserted. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {sanskrit}
Missing number, treated as zero. \select@language {sanskrit}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \select@language {sanskrit}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Undefined control sequence. \select@language {english}
Command \rmfamily invalid in math mode. \select@language {english}
Missing $ inserted. \begin{document}
fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature" Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'Renderer=AAT/OpenType/Graphite'.
fontspec warning: "no-mapping" Input mapping not (yet?) supported in LuaTeX.
fontspec warning: "no-mapping" Input mapping not (yet?) supported in LuaTeX.
Hindi is not supported with LuaTeX.
Overfull \hbox (5.5174pt too wide) in paragraph
```

my document

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{Brill}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\setsansfont{Lato}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=harvardkyoto]{Sanskrit 2003}
%\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=harvardkyoto]{Sanskrit 2003}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}

\begin{document}

Here's some text in the default font,
Charis, and {\sanskritfont
अत्र देवनागरीलिप्युदाहरणम् वर्तते| \par}



\begin{sanskrit}
गरीलिप्युदा हरणम् 
\end{sanskrit}


\begin{hindi}
गरीलिप्युदा हरणम् 
\end{hindi}













\end{document}
```

Comment: LuaTeX doesn't support interchar classes (yet, maybe it will). So there's little hope you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for character classes in LuaTeX and, apparently, Sanskrit needs them in `polyglossia`.

Using LuaLaTeX seems impossible, at the moment.